# Prove or disprove $\max(|x_1|, |y_1|)+ \max(|x_2|, |y_2|) \ge\sqrt{(x_1+x_2)^2+(y_1+y_2)^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, real-numbers

Let's consider following set of conditions under some four real numbers $x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2$:

$$
\begin{cases} x_1y_1<0  \\  
x_2y_2 < 0 \\
(x_1+x_2)(y_1+y_2) \ge 0 \\
\end{cases}
$$

I want to prove or disaprove the following inequality:

$$\max(|x_1|, |y_1|)+ \max(|x_2|, |y_2|) \ge\sqrt{(x_1+x_2)^2+(y_1+y_2)^2}$$

And I'm really confused about this one. I found it almost impossible to be satisfies but I cannot find any counterexample. Could you please give me a hint how I can prove or disprove it ?

Comment: I don't think the conditions can be all satisfied, because multiplying the first two gives $x_1x_2y_1y_2 > 0$ but multiplying the last two gives $x_1x_2y_1y_2 < 0$.

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much for your comment. I don't know what the last two conditions were doing there. I updated my question to be properly defined.

Comment: How is it "almost impossible to be satisfied" but also "I cannot find a counter example"?

Comment: It's that my intuition suggests me that there will be example which will smash the inequality but I cannot find such

Comment: I think this is true. $RHS\leq |x_1+x_2+y_1+y_2|\leq |x_1+y_1|+|x_2+y_2|$. From the conditions, we have |x_i+y_i|\leq \max (|x_i|,|y_i|)$.